# System V init scripts

Tags: init

How do I list the services running on an instance started by System V init scripts?

I attempted to run 'service  | --status-all>' with no luck.

Comment: Theres no pipe `service --status-all`

Comment: I use ' service --status-all 2>&1',.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is simple. There is no command/function called `--status-all`:

```
$ service | --status-all
Usage: service < option > | --status-all | [ service_name [ command | --full-restart ] ]
--status-all: command not found
```

In the usage the bar `|` means `OR`. So, what the usage is telling you is using either:

- `service <option>`: option here is `start`, `stop`, etc.
- `service --status-all`: which give you a list of the status of all the services that supports status.
- `service service_name command`: the service name is obviously the name of any service in the init and command is `start`, `stop`, `restart`, etc.
- `service service_name --full-restart`: calls the `stop` command, then call the `start` command.